# EF Core .FromSql to run stored procedure can't handle aliases when hosted on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.1 website using EF Core that works fine when running on my local PC (Windows 10 Pro) in VS and in IIS and connected to the Live database.  However when I deploy this website to the live web server (Windows Server 2012 r2), still connected to the same database I get the error below:

> The required column 'DateLive' was not present in the results of a
>   'FromSql' operation

I've tried the following 2 ways to call a stored procedure and both give the same error when on the live server, yet work fine locally.

```
List<SqlParameter> paramList = new List<SqlParameter>();
paramList.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = customerId });
DbParameter[] parameters = paramList.ToArray();
//Method 1
return _context.Set<sp_GetCustomer_Result>().FromSql($"sp_GetCustomer @CustomerId", parameters);
//Method 2
return _context.GetCustomers.FromSql($"sp_GetCustomer @CustomerId", parameters);
```

There are no issues when the store procedure does a plain select as below

```
select DateTimeEntered from Customers
```

But when there is an alias used as below I get this error.

```
select DateTimeEntered as DateLive from Customers
```

This has to be down to a difference between the web server and my PC as everything else is the same, but I can't work out what the difference is.

Comment: Its unlikely its the webserver, since its not involved in ASP.NET Core at all, except that it acts as reverse proxy. Are you really sure you are connecting to the same database? I mean did you check your `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` ? For me it sounds more like your local version is running in development environment (and hence values from `appsettings.Development.json` have precedence over `appsettings.json` while your productive application runs on `Produiction` environment (set via `ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable) and hence connecting somewhere else

Comment: Do you use the same .net core verion for .net core sdk in development and .net core runtime in server?